# How to send authenticate user laravel to vue props?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i want to send authenticate user data to props vue. then i tried this:
`:user="{{ Auth::user() }}"` but got an errors.

[image]

Comment: jesus your font

Comment: what's wrong sir? :)

Comment: It's.... Interesting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try to convert the user object to JSON

```
:user="{{ json_encode(Auth::user()) }}"
```

Comment: you're right, need to convert to javascript object. Thanks :)

Comment: we can also use laravel blade `@json` like this: `:user='@json(Auth::user())'`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is one tini tiny mistake here! You are using `{{ Auth::user() }}` which is JSON or Array! If you want to store User's ID in `user` Attribute, you have to use `{{ Auth::user()->id }}`.
If you want to Authenticate user first, you can use if Condition! For example,

```
@if(Auth::user())
    // Your Markup Code
@endif
```

Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use It like this

```
<post-comment user="{{ Auth::user() }}"></post-comment>
```

Using `:` is reserved for data binding for properties from data object aka Vue App Model / State.

I guess you are using this into Laravel Blade.

Dynamic Props - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props

However your way would works only If `Auth::user()` method return the Boolean (true/false).Otherwise It would throw an error in Browser Console.

Comment: Without `:` it would pass down what Auth::user method return.As mentioned `:` is used when you have defined some properties in `data: {}` of your Vue Instance.

Comment: then how i can get user data?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking... `user` is still prop and you can display it into the `<post-comment>` component.